# How to add an ImageIcon in java? this code is not working

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, embedded-resource, imageicon

I want to add an ImageIcon to the Panel, but I got this Exception
(

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toExternalForm()" because "location" is null
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javax.swing.JLabel.setBounds(int, int, int, int)"
```

**because "this.LABEL2" is null** and I do not know how to solve it , help me please.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class ShowQR extends JFrame{
    private JPanel PANEL;

    private JLabel LABEL2;

    private ImageIcon ICON;
    
    

    public ShowQR(){
    
    super("Choose background color");
    

    
    ICON = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("qr-code2.png"));
    LABEL2= new JLabel(ICON);
    
    PANEL.setLayout(null);

    LABEL2.setBounds(50, 50, 50, 50);

    PANEL.add(LABEL2);


    add(PANEL);
    
    setVisible(true);



    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);



    setSize(400,400);
    }
}
```

Comment: The root cause here probably is, that your specified image cannot be found in this path. Did you make sure to specify the correct path to the image? The java tutorial on [How to use Icons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) has some good examples on how to load the image properly.

Comment: `ICON = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("qr-code2.png"));` are you sure that `icon` is not null and `qr-code2.png` located in expected location.

Comment: Variable names should not be capitalized. Learn and follow Java naming conventions. You will find the proper conventions in any code examples found in text books or online tutorials.

Answer (score -1):

```
public ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(Test.class.getResource("give image path"));
```

Please try this way. give the image path in you file structure.

Answer (score -1):

This might help

```
ICON = new ImageIcon("specify icon path here "); 

//you might need to scale the icons size 
Image image = image.getImage().getScaledInstance(width, height,Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);

ImageIcon ICON2 = new ImageIcon(image);

LABEL2 = new JLabel(ICON2);

LABEL2.setBounds(x,y,width,height);
```

Comment: Please specify the way to add the path